# Error converting data type varchar to float, data with letters and numebers

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The column I am drawing data from has both numbers and letters randomly distributed and I need both in order to differentiate them.

Example: 207RG0100X (column name is C1)

I am trying to join two other tables with a temp table I created that holds this column of data, but I keep getting the varchar to float conversion error. I know float has precedence over varchar in terms of data types, but the ways I found around this include ISNUMERIC() and since my data contains both numbers and letters, I don't believe that will not work. Any advice?

```
SELECT CAST([TAXONOMY CODE] AS Varchar(max)) AS Taxonomy, [SPECIALTY CODE] AS ProviderCode INTO #TaxonomyCodes FROM PS.TaxonomyCode WHERE [TAXONOMY CODE] LIKE '%X'

SELECT Taxonomy, ProviderCode, P.ProviderID, ProcedureCode
FROM #TaxonomyCodes TC, Database..ClaimDetail CD, Database..Claim C, Database..Provider P
WHERE TC.ProviderCode = P.PrescriberType1 AND CD.ClaimID = C.ClaimID AND C.ProviderID = P.ProviderId
```

Comment: First your query makes no sense. It references an alias (PC) not defined in the query. You also have a cross join whther that is intended or not. And it is an extremely bad habit to use implict syntax - you would have noticed the problem right away if you had used explict joins. Why are you using a join syntax that has been replaced with something far betterin the last century?

Comment: That pc should be C. I made changes when I was adding the comment to make it a little bit more anonymous and forgot to change that one. This type of join is what I was taught in school and so I've stuck to it. So the join is not the problem, it is the conversion.

Comment: Is your error on the first or second query? What is the exact text of the error.

Comment: Likely you need to read this if you think implict joins are acceptable:http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Programmers-ebook/dp/B00A376BB2/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1379965048&sr=1-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns

Comment: It does not make sense to use 'WHERE [TAXONOMY CODE] LIKE '%X'' in the same query. Rather Insert into the temp table all records, while doing the cast, and then in the second query you can add an extra where clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you data is of alphanumeric type, then you should store it in the temp table as varchar(xx), and not of float type. If the tables from which you are combining the data have different data types in columns, you can cast the float as CAST (floatColumn as VARCHAR(xx)). I cannot help much unless you post some SQL query to give a better idea.

Comment: Made an edit to give a coding example. I tried to CAST() as VarChar but to no avail.

Comment: But did you cast the right thing to varchar (And please don't use max unless you think the field will have more than 4000 characters).

Comment: I believe I did. This is the overall problem and so that's what I do not know. I put a CAST() within the second SELECT statement on the Taxonomy column as CAST(Taxonomy AS VarChar(50)) but that did not work.